# Create and authenticate access tokens

Tags: security, oauth, authorization

I am planning to create a small application that users can login to use. To provide API access, I plan to provide them with access tokens just like a lot of services provide.

When users login with email/password, I search for email address and match the password hash against that database entry. How can I create an access token though, something like GitHub:

```
ghp_36-characters
```

I have seen GitHub's tokens to always start with `ghp_` followed by 36 characters. Maybe the length of the characters can be a little more or less some times, but that's their format. How do they get a deterministic length and a specific format?

Possibilities I considered:

1. Encrypt the user ID with a strong encryption algorithm and a strong encryption password
2. Generate a random string
3. Use JWTs

Problems with each of those approaches:

1. The length of the string would depend upon the length of the user ID followed by encryption padding and other pieces of the equation. Also, I don't think it's possible to make it follow a specific format.
2. I can generate a random string, and store its hash like passwords, but then how can I find the entry in database to authenticate it against? What I mean is, I won't have a known value to compare the unknown value against in the database.
3. JWTs would heavily depend on the length of the string to encode and are extremely long even for really small data. Again, they have their own structure which won't be possible to escape.

Following a specific format is not a requirement for my application, so I can use any of these options successfully (possibly not the second one), but I'm curious to know how all services achieve this.

Comment: 2: Don’t store the hash, just store the actual token.

Comment: Won't that go against some standard security practices?

Comment: Arguably yes, it's a good idea to store hashes, so disregard my previous comment. However, just a standard unsalted hash is fine then, so you can simply hash the token of incoming requests and search for the exact result in the database. See https://security.stackexchange.com/q/151257/719.

Comment: Thank you for that link. I'll go ahead with storing hashes then.